# Recursive database viewing

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have this situation. Starting from a table, I have to check all the records that match a key. If records are found, I have to check another table using a key from the first table and so on, more on less on five levels. There is a way to do this in a recursive way, or I have to write all the code "by hand"? The language I am using is Visual Fox Pro. If this is is not possible, is it al least possible to use recursion to popolate a treeview?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a relation between tables. For example:

```
USE table_1.dbf IN 0 SHARED
USE table_2.dbf IN 0 SHARED
SET ORDER TO TAG key_field OF table_2.cdx IN table_2
SET RELATION TO key_field INTO table_2 ADDITIVE IN table_1
```

First two commands open table_1 and table_2. Then you have to set the order/index of table_2. If you don't have an index for the key field then this will not work. The final command sets the relation between the two tables on the key field.

From here you can browse both tables and table_2's records will be filtered based on table_1's key field. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, but what if the hierarchy allows recursive 4, 5 or more levels deep.  Your sample stops fixed at two.  Tamar is correct that more info about the table and hiearchy requirements would be needed.

Comment: I agree we need more info. This was an example on how to set up relations in vfp if he didn't know how.

Answer (score 0):

If the tables have similar structure or you only need to look at a few fields, you could write a recursive routine that receives the name of the table, the key to check, and perhaps the fields you need to check as parameters. The tricky part, I guess, is knowing what to pass down to the next call.

I don't think I can offer any more advice without at least seeing some table structures.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering so late, but the problem was of course that the recursion wasn't a viable solution since I had to search inside multiple tables. So I resolved by doing a simple 2-Level search in the tables that I needed.

Thank you very much for the help, and sorry again for answering so late.